# "Save as" OS dialog appearing when trying to download file with Selenium after Chrome version update

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

"Save as" OS dialog appearing when trying to download file with Selenium.
The dialog appearing when performing downloading manually too.
It worked properly till yesterday, I did not change nothing in my Selenium code recently.
The only change was  - Chrome updated to 117 version today.
I updated chromedriver for 117 version too, but it did not resolve the problem.
How can I fix this issue?
**UPD**
I already have the following settings:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "NUL");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
var downloadDir = Paths.get("downloads").toAbsolutePath().toString(); 
var prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("directory_upgrade", true);
prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check Chrome Version Compatibility, Clear browser datas etc.
2. Update Selenium WebDriver
3. Verify Download Settings

Go to **Settings**.
Scroll down and click on "Privacy and security" in the left sidebar.
Click on "Site settings."
Scroll down and click on "Additional content settings."
Click on "Automatic downloads."
Ensure that "Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file" is not enabled.

And i can recommend  you some code change as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": "/path/to/your/download/directory",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

**UPD**
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093248/chromedriver-version-117-forces-save-as-dialog-how-to-bypass-selenium-jav?rq=1) try removing `--incognito` from chrome options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but:
1) and 2) I wrote explicitly that I updated the chromedriver accordingly to updated Chrome version.
Nothing to clear since each time new Chrome session is started.
Also your code is for Python while I'm using Java, I mentioned that inappropriate tag. But I guess I know how to do the same with Java

Comment: When selenium open crome put time sleep and try this settings change -> "Go to Settings. Scroll down and click on "Privacy and security" in the left sidebar. Click on "Site settings." Scroll down and click on "Additional content settings." Click on "Automatic downloads." Ensure that "Ask when a site tries to download files automatically after the first file" is not enabled." maybe it will work

Comment: I guess some can be done with some command added to prefs / options... But I will try, thank you

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093248/chromedriver-version-117-forces-save-as-dialog-how-to-bypass-selenium-jav?rq=1) Check this also, have a nice day.

Comment: The referenced solution worked! Thank you! I updated your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Issue related to Download Bubbles feature added to chrome

chrome://flags/#download-bubble

Turn off in ruby:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.local_state = { browser: { enabled_labs_experiments: ['download-bubble-v2@2', 'download-bubble@2'] } }
```

Turn off in c#

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("browser", new { enabled_labs_experiments = new string[] { "download-bubble@2" } });         
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("browser", new { enabled_labs_experiments = new string[] { "download-bubble-v2@2" } });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the question is about Java, not C# or Ruby

Comment: Yeah i know that but it the same problem and solution just in a different language